# What does `same WSFC cluster can run multiple FCIs (multiple resource groups)` mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#FCIelements

> the same WSFC cluster can run multiple FCIs (multiple resource
> groups), depending on your hardware capacity, such as CPUs, memory,
> and number of disks.

I understand that the fci nodes MUST belong to the same cluster (WSFC). For example: I have created a WSFC, and added 2 nodes and shared disk to it. This is what I understand by WSFC cluster with multiple FCIs (FCI = a node).

The above quote confuses me. What does `same WSFC cluster can run multiple FCIs (multiple resource groups)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a single server can run multiple SQL Server instances, you can install on the same WSFC multiple FCI. In this way you can run for example FCI-A on node A and FCI-B on node B.

You need more shared disk because each FCI needs it own disk and you need enough hardware resources to run both instances on the same node (CPU and RAM). And you need also more sql licenses as the secondary node is no more passive.

Comment: Curiously may I ask - Can FCI-A and FCI-B be on node 1?

Comment: yes you can fail over an istance on each node so you can have both instances in the same node

Comment: Suppose I need to install 2 sql servers using fci technology. 2 nodes for sqlsvr1 and 2 nodes for sqlsvr2. Does it make any sense to have these 4 nodes in 1 cluster or better to have 2 separate clusters?

Comment: For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/install/sql-server-failover-cluster-installation?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-a-failover-cluster - You must have one WSFC group for each failover cluster instance you want to configure.

Comment: Maybe you can create a 3 nodes WFCI using the 3rd node as spare node for both instances

Comment: Agree but do I need 2 wsfc or can I do this in 1 wsfc?

Comment: you need one wsfc with 2 FCI and 3 nodes.

Comment: But the documentation says `You must have one WSFC group for each failover cluster instance you want to configure. `. Doesn't this mean that 1 wsfc can have 1 fci.

Comment: WSFC group is not equal to WSFC. A single WSFC can have multiple groups of resoruces (ie FCI). You will havet the two instances in different WSFC resource groups.